# What does "log" mean in "The log-transformed population trajectories were modeled as a first order autoregressive process and the F-ratios for..."?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "log" mean here?

> The log-transformed population trajectories were modeled as a first
> order autoregressive process and the F-ratios for the effects of
> habitat configuration and strain (main effects) were based on the
> random variation between these trajectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is short for logarithm. Log transformation is a statistical function. To be honest I don’t fully understand it, but there is a complete explanation [here](https://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/log.html).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: For data that vary over many orders of magnitude, i.e. those with an exponential relationship, computing the logarithm of the data can turn something messy into something with clearer meaning.  The actual mathematical relationship doesn't change, but our monkey brains are better at recognizing relatively straightforward linear relationships.  Logs turn exponential relationships into linear ones, in short.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation dear @Jason Patterson. Another question: Is it short for "logarithm" or "logarithmic" ?

Comment: It's a piec of mathematical notation, a three-letter function (like sin cos tan), and so not really part of English.  You couldn't "expand" the abbreviation to "logarithm" or "logarithmic"

Comment: @MostafaAhmadi As with many things in science and mathematics, though there is supposed to be standardization, things can vary from place to place, so if this matters to you in mathematics, science, or computer science, check with your instructors if there is uncertainty.   That said, yes, log is definitely used conversationally/instructionally, and, as you found, as an abbreviation for the noun "logarithm."  If you needed the adjective "logarithmic" you would generally say the whole word.  It's a long, strange word with a clean, short abbreviation, and mathematicians and scientists are lazy.